# What does the number under the heart mean?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

In *Animal Crossing: Pocket Camp*, there are two numbers when your friendship level increases with an animal. The first one is obviously the friendship level, I do not know what the second one is.

**What is the second number?**

[image]

Comment: Possibly the amount that the friendship level has increased ?

Comment: No, friendship levels only go up one by one (24 to 25 to 26...) never more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called *Friendship Points*. The amount of friendship points you require to level up your friendship level increase per level e.g

- 1 Point for level 1
- 4 additional points to level 2
- 4 additional points to level 3
- 6 additional points to level 4 etc.

It shows this on the [Wiki](https://animalcrossingpocketcamp.gamepedia.com/Villagers). While you only go up up one level at a time you gain multiple  *Friendship Points*.

Sources:

[Friendship Levels](https://animalcrossingpocketcamp.gamepedia.com/Villagers#Friendship_Levels)

[Video  Observation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqZkV0QVJU0)

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit complex of a system but I get it. I read the link, but I can't understand if there's a way to make the number lower depending on items placed on the campsite or what the animal is wearing... Also why it says "+2" on my screenshot since I'm at max level (25)

Comment: @MicroMachine I assume you can still earn the points but they won't contribute to the level anymore. And why would you want to make the number?

Comment: to gain level in less steps?

Comment: @MicroMachine but the more points you have the less steps you have to take to level up. Why lower the number?

Comment: in your link they are called “points to next level “ the higher the number the more difficult or slow it is to raise friendship level

Comment: @MicroMachine Ah. I see. No what is meant by that is the necessary points that you require to get to the next level. When it says +2 That means 2 points to the four points or however much points that you need. The higher the Friendship Points you receive the quicker you will level up.